# Android: Excepção ao executar Toast.makeText

Tags: android

Ola, 
estou a obter uma excepção quando é executado o `Toast.makeText`:

```
public void onClick(View view){
(...)
CharSequence text1 = "Please insert a number.";
 int id= view.getId();
(...)
    else if(id== R.id.buttonOK){
                if(editText.getText().toString().matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Já tentei usar como primeiro argumento:

**getApplicationContext()**

**this**

**MyActivity.this**

**view.getContext()**

Mas obtenho sempre a mesma excepção. Também já alterei o text1 e continuo a obter a excepção.
Coloquei um Log.d dentro do IF para perceber se o problema estava no IF, mas eu consigo entrar dentro do IF, a excepção é gerada no Toast.makeText.

Excepção:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

Alguma ideia para resolver isto?

Comment: já tentou utilizar `getActivity().getBaseContext()` ?

Comment: @sicachester já consegui solucionar o meu problema e nada tinha a ver com o Toast era um erro no IF-ELSE :\
Obrigada na mesma!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu !! contribua com a comunidade, poste sua solução como resposta !

Answer (score 1):

O seu erro era de indentação:

```
public void onClick(View view){
(...)
CharSequence text1 = "Please insert a number.";
 int id= view.getId();
(...)
    else if(id== R.id.buttonOK){
                if(editText.getText().toString().matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

**Correto:**

```
public void onClick(View view){
(...)
CharSequence text1 = "Please insert a number.";
 int id= view.getId();
(...)

if(ALGUMA COISA){

...

} else if(id== R.id.buttonOK){
                if(editText.getText().toString().matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```